# Inconsistent Behavior On Windows 10 and Windows 7 In EventTrigger Implementation

Tags: wpf, windows, eventtrigger

I am currently implementing a small UI tweak on a button. When I drag an object to be dropped over the button, I want the button's background to be the same when the mouse is over the button(no object being dragged).

So far, I was able to make it work using EventTriggers.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button AllowDrop="True" Width="100" Height="100">
            <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Color x:Key="ButtonDefaultBackgroundColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>
                    <Color x:Key="ButtonDefaultBackgroundMouseOverColor">#FFBEE6FD</Color>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DragEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard TargetProperty="Background.Color">
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0" To="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultBackgroundMouseOverColor}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DragLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard TargetProperty="Background.Color">
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0" To="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultBackgroundColor}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Drop">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard TargetProperty="Background.Color">
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0" To="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultBackgroundColor}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In Windows 10, the behavior is just as I expected. However, this is not true when I tested in Windows 7.

What do you think is the reason for this? Workarounds?

**EDIT:**
In Windows 7, the background color of the button does not change.

Comment: What *specifically* happens unexpectedly when running on Windows 7?

Comment: I edited my question.